# How to get selected option

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a dropdown as:

```
var hidDivSpan1 = $('<div></div>').addClass('span3');
var hidlabel1 = $('<label></label>').text('New Status: ');
var hidSelect = $('<select name="Status" id="DropdownStatus">').addClass('span3');
var hidOption1 = $('<option value="ON"></option>').text('ON');
var hidOption2 = $('<option value="OFF"></option>').text('OFF');
var hidOption3 = $('<option value="UNKNOWN"></option>').text('UNKNOWN');    
hidSelect.append(hidOption1);
hidSelect.append(hidOption2);
hidSelect.append(hidOption3);
hidDivSpan1.append(hidlabel1);
hidDivSpan1.append(hidSelect);
```

Now i have a save button and on click of this button i want to get the selected option of the above dropdown. For that what i am doing is :

```
hidSavBtn.on("click", function () {
//var selectedVal=$("#DropdownStatus option:selected").text();
var selectedVal=$('#DropdownStatus').val();
});
```

From the above ,i have used both code to get the selected option, but both code returns me the first option always. 
If i am selection the second option i.e. OFF, then also i am getting on as my selected text or value.

I am unable to figure out how can i get the actual selected value.

Looking forward to your solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you have duplicated `id` attributes - use classes and traverse the DOM to find the `select` relative to the clicked save button.

Comment: make sure that you have unique `id`s for all DOM elements

Comment: yes, i checked. I have unique ids for all DOM Elements

Comment: Are you sure? Even when you append multiple `#DropdownStatus`?

Comment: Ok, so what can i do to rectify my above peice of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an error somewhere, but you should be calling:

```
var selectedResult = $("#DropdownStatus").val();
```

If you want to find the value of the selected option

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gc69teu6/1/)